# how to debug swift 5.8 source code in xcode 14.3

Tags: swift, xcode

Has anyone debugged the source code of swift 5.8 using Xcode14.3?  Why I follow this article https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/HowToGuides/GettingStarted.md, setting breakpoints does not take effect.

I can compile, but setting breakpoints in my test swift file doesn't work.

Here are the parameters I use：
utils/build-script --skip-build-benchmarks --skip-watchos --skip-tvos --swift-darwin-supported-archs "$(uname -m)" --release-debuginfo --debug-swift-stdlib --swift-disable-dead-stripping

utils/build-script --swift-darwin-supported-archs "$(uname -m)" --xcode --clean